# Как правильно вызвать метод vue?

Tags: vue.js

Мне нужно вызвать метод и передать в него id товара. Как лучше это сделать?

```
<template>
<form @click.prevent="addToCart">
                    <input type="hidden" v-model="id" name="id" />
                    <button v-on="addToCart" type="submit">
                        Добавить в корзину
                    </button>
                </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        id: {
            type: Number,
            default: "NULL",
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: "NULL",
        },
        price: {
            type: String,
            default: "NULL",
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart(){
            axios.post('/api/cart/add', {
                id: id
                })
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.data.status) {
                        console.log(res.data);
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err.responsense.data);
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Зачем вам передавть `id` в метод как параметр? Форма одна, `id` тоже только один. Обращайтесь к нему как к `this.id` внутри метода да и все.

Comment: Раз как параметр, то для начала надо сделать метод с параметром. `addToCart(id) { ... }`, во вторых вызывать метод с указанием фактических параметров `v-on="addToCart(id)"`

Comment: @Sergey При нажатии ничего не происходит. В консоли тоже ничего

Comment: @smellyshovel Мне выдает ошибки даже без нажатия на кнопки `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 (Too Many Requests)`

Comment: я точно не знаю, но может вместо `v-on=...` надо написать `@click=...` (сам так делаю) или `v-on:click=...`

Comment: @Sergey Все равно ничего. Странно

Comment: @дело в методе. Буду разбираться

Comment: @Vladimir сервер блокирует запросы по причине того, что их слишком много от вас послтупает. Либо поступа**ло**. Возможно, раньше в коде был бесконечный цикл. Возможно, он есть и сейчас. Возможно, этот компонент вы вставляете на страницу слишком много раз.